Jacobi two square's theorem last step to conclusion
The Jacobi two-square theorem is: "The number of representations of n as a sum of two squares is four times the difference between the number of divisors of n congruent to 1 modulo 4 and the number of divisors of n congruent to 3 modulo 4."
I can understand until the last step of calculation
$$\left(\sum^\infty_{n=-\infty}{x^{n^2}}\right)^2=1+4\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{x^{4n-3}}{1-x^{4n-3}}-\frac{x^{4n-1}}{1-x^{4n-1}}\right),$$ but I cannot understand how is it related to the statement of the theorem?

Could you add a link or reference to the proof you're following? I would be interested to see a route to this identity that is analytic, but ideally without heavy-weight machinery from modular forms.

Sure, it's a beautiful proof only by changing variables, differentiate, and dividing. https://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/~mikeh/webpapers/paper21.pdf

Before reading this, I actually proved with Gaussian composite and case discussions that if a composite has all different \equiv 1(mod 4) prime factors (ex. 2^757^2), there're 2^(d_1(n)-1) ways to write as 2 square sums. It looks ok but has difficulty to proceed to more cases, and it's much longer than the classical proof. I never arranged it into electronic format.
One thing I find it not that cool at first is the four times, just one of 4 is positive integer solution. but I soon realized that's to put a general formula to avoid discussion related to 2a^2.

This question is not of research level, but I feel like answering it.
Let $m$ be a positive integer. If you multiply each term with each term on the left-hand side, you can see that the coefficient of $x^m$ equals
$$\#\{(n_1,n_2)\in\mathbb{Z}^2:m=n_1^2+n_2^2\}.$$
On the other hand, if you develop the two fractions on the right-hand side into two geometric series, namely
$$\frac{x^{4n-3}}{1-x^{4n-3}}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty x^{(4n-3)k}\qquad\text{and}\qquad \frac{x^{4n-1}}{1-x^{4n-1}}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty x^{(4n-1)k},$$
you can see that the coefficient of $x^m$ equals $4$ times the difference
$$\#\{(n,k)\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}^2:m=(4n-3)k\}-\#\{(n,k)\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}^2:m=(4n-1)k\}.$$
Note that here $4n-3$ runs through the positive integers congruent to $1$ modulo $4$, while $4n-1$ runs through the positive integers congruent to $3$ modulo $4$. The result follows. (The analytic steps performed above are justified, because for $|x|<1$ the ensuing series converge absolutely.)

Do we really need a positive radius of convergence? All steps are valid at the level of formal power series...

@PietroMajer I agree. One can carry out the steps above in the topological ring $\mathbb{C}[[x]]$, say, and get the same result. Working with convergent power series is natural though, as the original identity is meant for such series.

Thank you! It's very clear.
